# Stop EBS Linux 2 (Node.js) from trying to do npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I'm trying to run a Node application on AWS Linux 2 on Elastic Beanstalk and need to install the dependencies using yarn. (My Node app causes errors if you try to use npm to install dependencies instead of yarn.)

I've already figured out [how to set up a script in .platform/hooks/prebuild/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67326448/5602521) to get it to run yarn, but even though it's running the yarn installation, it still also tries to run npm install, which errors out, causing my deploy to fail.

**So I need to figure out how to prevent the default npm install step from running.**

(Does anyone know what file that command is run from in the AWS Linux 2 setup process? I was wondering if I could just add another script in .platform/hooks/prebuild/ that would modify that file to prevent the call to npm.)

Comment: Can you share your deployment files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can avoid `npm install`

When you deploy a `node_modules` directory to an Amazon Linux 2 Node.js platform version, Elastic Beanstalk assumes that you're providing your own dependency packages, and avoids installing dependencies specified in a `package.json` file.

[source doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-dependencies.html)